# How to quickly show a rendered image in Swing?

Tags: java, image, swing

I have an image saved as byte array, which is already rendered and will fit perfectly into my GUI application (no filtering, rotation, resizing or color transformation is needed). What is the fastest way to show the image?

I'm not sure what Swing is doing internally with the image before it actually shows it. But I try to bypass all these steps and directly show it without any additional Swing processing. Can you think of a way to do this?

Comment: [ImageIcon accepts a byte array as a constructor argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28byte[]%29)

Comment: Do you mean you want to render the image yourself, without using any Swing APIs?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea! I get an image as byte array, which was already rendered elsewhere and then I try to show it in the GUI as quick as possible without any further processing by the Swing API

Comment: `I try to show it in the GUI as quick as possible without any further processing by the Swing API` - just do it. Don't worry about "as quickly as possible". Swing components like JLabel, or Graphics.drawImage() will paint the image fast enough. Don't complicate your code trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I was just wondering if I can bypass it, because I could just load that byte array directly on the graphic card without touching it anymore. So every additional process step by Swing is kinda redundant. And I don't know what Swing is doing internally until the image is finally on the screen.